# Python - How to filter on Facebook Marketing API AdAccount.get_lead_gen_forms?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

How can i define a filter for Facebook Marketing API for the method get_lead_gen_forms? I have tried passing some params, but nothing works.

I need to filter by date because the number of data is exceeding my limit.
Here's my code (*** the code already works, need help with the filter**):

```
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount

FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)
account = AdAccount('act_accountid')
leadgenforms = account.get_lead_gen_forms()
```

And here is the params that i have tried:

```
# attempt 1
params = {
        'time_range': {
            'since': date_start, 
            'until': date_end
            }
         }
leadgenforms = account.get_lead_gen_forms(params=params)

# attempt 2
 params = {
         'filtering': [{ 
             'field': 'created_time', 
             'operator': 'GREATER_THAN', 
             'value': date_start }]
         }
leadgenforms = account.get_lead_gen_forms(params=params)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should filter for the field `time_created`  instead of `created_time`.

From the section **Filtering Leads** of the [doc here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving):

> This example filters leads based on timestamps. Timestamps should be
>   Unix timestamp.
>
> ```
> curl -G \
>   --data-urlencode 'filtering=[ 
>     { 
>       "field": "time_created", 
>       "operator": "GREATER_THAN", 
>       "value": 1516682744 
>     } 
>   ]' \
>   -d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
>   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/<AD_ID>/leads
> ```

So, in the second attempt example:

```
# attempt 2
 params = {
         'filtering': [{ 
             'field': 'time_created', 
             'operator': 'GREATER_THAN', 
             'value': date_start }]
         }
leadgenforms = account.get_lead_gen_forms(params=params)
```

you should use, ad `date_start`, a date in format of the unix timestamp:

> number of seconds since the Unix Epoch

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @KauannH.deOliveira  You should filter for the field `time_created` instead of `created_time`.  See my update

Comment: The problem continues, i have checked the source code of python sdk [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/blob/master/facebook_business/adobjects/adaccount.py) and i saw that method get_lead_gen_forms only accept the field **query** for params.

Comment: Avoid GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, GREATER_THAN works fine for me using your approach, thanks!